# I can't resolve null check operator used on a null value error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, null

```
Uint8List? _file;

SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                  width: 45,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Null check operator used on a null value. I know the reason for this error but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

With Uint8List? the value I defined as 'This value may be null', with _file! I'm trying to call it with 'This value is not null'. This is the cause of the error but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You can fix it by making sure it has a value before using it... Right now it is null, so you are getting an error for telling the compiler it can't be null, while in fact, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do a null check 1st.

```dart
if (_file != null)
  SizedBox(
    height: 45,
    width: 45,
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Or

```dart
image: _file != null
    ? DecorationImage(
        image: MemoryImage(_file),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
      )
    : null,
```

Comment: But I'm not specifying here that _file is a data type of type Uint8List. Wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: I think it is safe to make data nullable and do null check while using it.

Comment: I tried both solutions but still getting the same error.  Do I need to change the Uint8List? _file part?

Comment: I think not, try to save the file and restart the idea. Also check other places where you are using `!`